# How do I prove isomorphism?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, graph-isomorphism

I need to prove this:
$$S_{\mathbb{N}}\cong S_{\mathbb{Z}}$$ ($S$ means permutation).

I'd like to get ideas how to prove it...

Thank you!

Comment: when is $S_n\cong S_m$ for $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$ ?

Comment: There is a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$. You can construct an explicit one if you wish. That will induce an isomorphism from one of the symmetric groups to the other.

Comment: @AndréNicolas - I don't understand, can you give me example to explain? Thank you!

Comment: @Robert.Sie - I know it's it's much harder then the example that you gave..

Comment: @Yoav Fridman - its not much harder, once you can answer my question, you should understand what you need to prove. From there its just one little step left. Andre already explained what you have to prove btw.

Comment: I hope I understand, can you give me little more help please?

Comment: Start from an explicit bijection $\sigma$ from the naturals to the integers. For example let $\sigma(1)-0$, $\sigma(2)=1$, $\sigma(3)=-1$. $\sigma(4)=2$, $\sigma(5)=-2$, and so on. Now define a mapping $\phi$ from $S(\mathbb{N})$ to $S(\mathbb{Z})$ as follows. If the permutation $\alpha$ takes the natural number $i$ to $j$, let $\phi(\alpha)$ take $\sigma(i)$ to $\sigma(j)$. You need to show this is a group isomorphism. Verification should be pretty mechanical. Effectively we are just renaming the element of $\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, you wish to construct an isomorphism $\alpha : S_\mathbb{N} \to S_\mathbb{Z}$.

But what are the elements of $S_\mathbb{N}$? They're just $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ bijective. Likewise for $\mathbb{Z}$.

Hint: there is some $g : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}$ that is bijective. Can you use this to construct an explicit isomorphism? What is a natural thing to do to some $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$?